# Tkinter Treeview call cannot find item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tcl, call

I have some items in a treeview that contain backslashes. This is normally fine however it seems that tk.call forcefully removes these backslashes. Is there any way to prevent this?

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

tv = Treeview(root)

iid = "aa\\bb"
tv.insert("", 'end', iid=iid, text=iid)
tv.tk.call(tv, "tag", "add", "new_tag", iid)

tv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> _tkinter.TclError: Item ab not found

**Python 3.11.1**

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It is weird that using backslash in an *item ID*.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a complete example

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to display using raw strings and a separate variable.  I think it could be adapted though.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = tk.Tk()

tv = Treeview(root)

iid = "aa\\bb"
iid_raw = r"aa\\bb"
print(iid)
tv.insert("", 'end', iid=iid, text=iid)
tv.tk.call(tv, "tag", "add", "new_tag", iid_raw)

tv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Encoding the iid to 'raw' worked as well, which might act a little more dynamic as you'd only have to set iid:

```
iid = "aa\\bb"
iid_raw = iid.encode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: It *shouldn't* require extra encoding. This sounds like a Tkinter bug specifically, given that going via the `call` method worked.